# ngClass not accepting 3 conditions

Tags: css, angular

I have given a condition for `[ngClass]` as follows:

`[ngClass]="{ 'disable-row': key.linkId && key.lob !== MK }"` 
It works with the following condition, but when I adding another && condition it stops working all together. The condition I was to give is:

```
[ngClass]="{ 'disable-row': key.linkId && key.lob !== MK && key.firstName === true}"
```

here firstName is a `checkbox` which returns a `boolean` `true` or `false`.

Comment: How can we say what is wrong? By looking at it and from your comment, it seems alright

Comment: Can you please paste here the code of checkbox that returns boolean?

Comment: Check whether it returns `true` when angular is compiling html. you can do it simply by `<div>{{key.firstName}}</div>` after your condition element

Comment: Does `key.firstName` evaluate to true? You can simplify your condition to: `[ngClass]="{ 'disable-row': key.linkId && key.lob !== MK && key.firstName}"` (I've removed the unnecessary check for true)

Comment: Also shouldn't MK be quoted as a string like `'MK'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
[ngClass]="( key.linkId == true &&  key.lob !== 'MK' && key.firstName === true)? 'disable-row' : ''"
```

Comment: I don't know how does it make any difference. Both techniques do the same thing

Comment: I just told you the most thorough and clear way of writing `ngClass` with some paranthesis and ternary operator. Please make sure that `key.firstName` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: I am not sure what I was doing wrong, but this condition worked perfectly. Using a ternary operator has fixed the issue. Although as mentioned by Kenny too, both the methods were basically doing the same thing. But this answer is great. Thank you.

Comment: @Bitly, see that in your code forget a singles quotes `key.lob !== 'MK'`, and yes, for me it's better the sintax `{'class':condition}`